# Why is measured width of divs different from browser measurement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a small tool to try several flexbox parameters. It can add and remove divs from a flexbox container and then shows the width of these added elements using jQuery. But the measured width is different from what I measure in the browser inspector.

Using the "plus" and "minus" buttons, elements can be added. The width of the first element should be correct, but the later elements are wrongly measured. What is going on here?

```js
function getWidth() {
  // true: include margins
  var v = parseFloat($(this).outerWidth(true)).toFixed(2);
  var span = '<span>Width: ' + v + '</span>';
  
  console.log(v);
  $(this).html(span);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Initialize.
  var items = 3;
  var itemsDiv = '<div class="item">';
  var HTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
    HTML += itemsDiv + 'Item ' + i + '</div>';
  }
  $('.container').html(HTML)
  var adjustment;

  // Add / remove items
  // Always keep at least one flex item.
  $('input[name="build"]').click(function() {
    adjustment = $(this).val();
    if (adjustment == "plus") {
      items += 1;
    }
    if (adjustment == "minus") {
      if (items > 1) {
        items -= 1;
      }
    }
    HTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
      HTML += itemsDiv + 'Item ' + i + '</div>';
    }
    $('.container').html(HTML);
    $('.item').each(getWidth);
  });

  // Flex direction
  // Select flex-direction radio buttons and get checked value.
  $('input[name="flex-direction"]').click(function() {
    var flexDirection = $('input[name="flex-direction"]:checked').val();
    $('.container').css('flex-direction', flexDirection);
  });

  // Flex wrap
  $('input[name="flex-wrap"]').click(function() {
    var flexWrap = $('input[name="flex-wrap"]:checked').val();
    $('.container').css('flex-wrap', flexWrap);
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
}

div.item {
  padding: 0;
  /* max-width: 80px; */
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./flexbox.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="flexbox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="base">
    <input type="button" name="build" value="plus" id="plus">
    <input type="button" name="build" value="minus" id="minus">
    <div class="container"></div>
    Flex Direction
    <input type="radio" name="flex-direction" id="row" value="row" checked>
    <label for="row">Row</label>
    <input type="radio" name="flex-direction" id="column" value="column">
    <label for="column">Column</label>
    <input type="radio" name="flex-direction" id="row-reverse" value="row-reverse">
    <label for="row-reverse">Row-Reverse</label>
    <input type="radio" name="flex-direction" id="column-reverse" value="column-reverse">
    <label for="column-reverse">Column-Reverse</label>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="flex-wrap" id="nowrap" value="nowrap" checked>
    <label for="nowrap">No Wrap</label>
    <input type="radio" name="flex-wrap" id="wrap" value="wrap">
    <label for="wrap">Wrap</label>
    <input type="radio" name="flex-wrap" id="wrap-reverse" value="wrap-reverse">
    <label for="wrap-reverse">Wrap-Reverse</label>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `function getWidth()` uses jQuerys `outerWidth()` with passed boolean `true`. Which means that it will include margins in its calculations. If you remove the boolean it will be fine.

Comment: @Paran0a I deliberately added the boolean because i wanted the total width of the element (i.e. with four elements, its 400px / 4 should give 100 px per element)

Answer (score 4):

The calculation is fine and the difference is due to the fact that you are calculating the width of the 1st one then you add a content inside it which will affect the other. Then you do the same with the second one, etc.

At the end all of them will have the same `outerWidth`<sup>1</sup> visually because they have the same content BUT while running the JS it's not the case and you cannot notice this.

Here is the code without adding content to your elements and you can clearly see that all the log give the same result simply because the HTML is not changing **during the width calculation**.

```js
function getWidth() {
  // true: include margins
  var v = parseFloat($(this).outerWidth(true)).toFixed(2);
  var span = '<span>Width: ' + v + '</span>';
  
  console.log(v);
  //$(this).html(span);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Initialize.
  var items = 3;
  var itemsDiv = '<div class="item">';
  var HTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
    HTML += itemsDiv + 'Item ' + i + '</div>';
  }
  $('.container').html(HTML)
  var adjustment;

  // Add / remove items
  // Always keep at least one flex item.
  $('input[name="build"]').click(function() {
    adjustment = $(this).val();
    if (adjustment == "plus") {
      items += 1;
    }
    if (adjustment == "minus") {
      if (items > 1) {
        items -= 1;
      }
    }
    HTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
      HTML += itemsDiv + 'Item ' + i + '</div>';
    }
    $('.container').html(HTML);
    $('.item').each(getWidth);
  });

  // Flex direction
  // Select flex-direction radio buttons and get checked value.
  $('input[name="flex-direction"]').click(function() {
    var flexDirection = $('input[name="flex-direction"]:checked').val();
    $('.container').css('flex-direction', flexDirection);
  });

  // Flex wrap
  $('input[name="flex-wrap"]').click(function() {
    var flexWrap = $('input[name="flex-wrap"]:checked').val();
    $('.container').css('flex-wrap', flexWrap);
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
}

div.item {
  padding: 0;
  /* max-width: 80px; */
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./flexbox.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="flexbox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="base">
    <input type="button" name="build" value="plus" id="plus">
    <input type="button" name="build" value="minus" id="minus">
    <div class="container"></div>
    Flex Direction
    <input type="radio" name="flex-direction" id="row" value="row" checked>
    <label for="row">Row</label>
    <input type="radio" name="flex-direction" id="column" value="column">
    <label for="column">Column</label>
    <input type="radio" name="flex-direction" id="row-reverse" value="row-reverse">
    <label for="row-reverse">Row-Reverse</label>
    <input type="radio" name="flex-direction" id="column-reverse" value="column-reverse">
    <label for="column-reverse">Column-Reverse</label>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="flex-wrap" id="nowrap" value="nowrap" checked>
    <label for="nowrap">No Wrap</label>
    <input type="radio" name="flex-wrap" id="wrap" value="wrap">
    <label for="wrap">Wrap</label>
    <input type="radio" name="flex-wrap" id="wrap-reverse" value="wrap-reverse">
    <label for="wrap-reverse">Wrap-Reverse</label>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, here is the state when you only add the content inside the first element AFTER calculating its width. We can clearly see that we don't have the same structure and not the same margin between elements thus the `outerWidth` of the second element will be different.

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
}

div.item {
  padding: 0;
  /* max-width: 80px; */
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
All the elements have the same outerwidth here
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item 0</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
We add the width calculation inside the first one and the margin will be reduced so the next one will be different
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><span>Width: 100.66</span></div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Here is the next states and you can clearly see the effect.

*The values used are simple placeholder*

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
}

div.item {
  padding: 0;
  /* max-width: 80px; */
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><span>Width: 100.66</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Width: 100.66</span></div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><span>Width: 100.66</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Width: 100.66</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Width: 100.66</span></div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><span>Width: 100.66</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Width: 100.66</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Width: 100.66</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Width: 100.66</span></div>
</div>
```

---

In the situation with 4 elements only the margin is affected, but when it comes to more elements the inner width may also get affected due to the shrink effect:

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
}

div.item {
  padding: 0;
  /* max-width: 80px; */
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item 0</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Width 100</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
</div>
```

---

If you want an accurate calculation, you should avoid changing the HTML content and the DOM structure **while doing the calculation.** You can update it before and after but not in the middle of the calculation by adding content.

<sup>1 : it's the width including margin since you are adding `true` to the jQuery function.</sup>

---

Based on a comment, here is a sample of your original code, where the `span` with the width info gets appended, and positioned absolute at the bottom. With this it won't affect the calculated values.

Stack snippet

```js
function getWidth() {
  // true: include margins
  var v = parseFloat($(this).outerWidth(true)).toFixed(2);
  var span = '<span>Width: ' + v + '</span>';
  
  //console.log(v);
  $(this).append(span);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Initialize.
  var items = 3;
  var itemsDiv = '<div class="item">';
  var HTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
    HTML += itemsDiv + 'Item ' + i + '</div>';
  }
  $('.container').html(HTML)
  var adjustment;

  // Add / remove items
  // Always keep at least one flex item.
  $('input[name="build"]').click(function() {
    adjustment = $(this).val();
    if (adjustment == "plus") {
      items += 1;
    }
    if (adjustment == "minus") {
      if (items > 1) {
        items -= 1;
      }
    }
    HTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
      HTML += itemsDiv + 'Item ' + i + '</div>';
    }
    $('.container').html(HTML);
    $('.item').each(getWidth);
  });

  // Flex direction
  // Select flex-direction radio buttons and get checked value.
  $('input[name="flex-direction"]').click(function() {
    var flexDirection = $('input[name="flex-direction"]:checked').val();
    $('.container').css('flex-direction', flexDirection);
  });

  // Flex wrap
  $('input[name="flex-wrap"]').click(function() {
    var flexWrap = $('input[name="flex-wrap"]:checked').val();
    $('.container').css('flex-wrap', flexWrap);
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
}

div.item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  /* max-width: 80px; */
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.item span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./flexbox.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="flexbox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="base">
    <input type="button" name="build" value="plus" id="plus">
    <input type="button" name="build" value="minus" id="minus">
    <div class="container"></div>
    Flex Direction
    <input type="radio" name="flex-direction" id="row" value="row" checked>
    <label for="row">Row</label>
    <input type="radio" name="flex-direction" id="column" value="column">
    <label for="column">Column</label>
    <input type="radio" name="flex-direction" id="row-reverse" value="row-reverse">
    <label for="row-reverse">Row-Reverse</label>
    <input type="radio" name="flex-direction" id="column-reverse" value="column-reverse">
    <label for="column-reverse">Column-Reverse</label>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="flex-wrap" id="nowrap" value="nowrap" checked>
    <label for="nowrap">No Wrap</label>
    <input type="radio" name="flex-wrap" id="wrap" value="wrap">
    <label for="wrap">Wrap</label>
    <input type="radio" name="flex-wrap" id="wrap-reverse" value="wrap-reverse">
    <label for="wrap-reverse">Wrap-Reverse</label>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also noticed this behaviour. I'm not sure how to go about this that the calculation only happens when the DOM change is finished.

Comment: @TMOTTM I think you miss understood ... *you* are changing the DOM by including a new text inside your element when calculating the width and you have to avoid this ... you can see in my example that adding `width: xxx` change the width of the element after the calculation is done thus change also the margin ... you should simply avoid this. In my first example the calculation is fine because you are not changing the dom

Comment: sure, that's right But I have to change the dom:)  using the "plus/minus" buttons, the elements are added and I want to monitor how their width changes whenever an element is added. So I have to add the elements, i.e. change the dom.

Comment: @TMOTTM and am not talking about the changes done with the "plus/minus" .. am talking about the changes done by the function that are calculating the width and are adding that information inside the div ... that what  I am trying to illustrate with my last snippet. The issue is there, After changing the DOM, you are calculating the width AND you are adding that information inside the divs so you are changing when doing the calculation

Comment: @TMOTTM It's ok to change the dom, but it's not ok to do it while doing the calculation, this is your issue, and that's why the first snippet is working fine ... We are changing the dom there but when doing the calculation the DOM is fixed thus the log is correct

Comment: I think now i get what you say. When printing to the console, the width is not changed by adding the label. So the question is, how can i add labels that don‘t affect the dom anymore? All caculations should be finished before anything gets added. I cant really figure out how to do this right now

Comment: @TMOTTM simply add the label outside, somewhere else ... don't add them inside the divs

Comment: That's quick fix option but would be less optimal because I think its most helpful if the items are labelled.

Comment: @TMOTTM but as you can see, adding the label will change the width of your element so this is clearly a bad idea, So in all the cases you will never have an accurate calculation because the lable should contain the width and that width should be caclulated before BUT when you will add it you will change the width again ...

Comment: @TMOTTM I added a sample at the end of this answer, showing one way how to accomplish that.

Comment: @TMOTTM And if that does do it, you need to loop twice, first time to calculate, second time adding the width info.

Comment: @LGSon yes good solution, I think it will be more clear for him now ;)

Comment: Perhaps one way to overcome the change in the width by measuring the width problem could be to hover the label when mouse over the element.

Comment: @TMOTTM, it's like position absolute. If you make the element in a way that it doesn't affect the flow it will work